# Laravel authentication and filters

Tags: laravel, authentication, filter

I need help, can someone tell me if my work is correct with the authentication users profiles? I have the next files:

file routes.php (I used only two groups for this example)

```
<?php
    //home
    Route::get('/',function()
    {
        return Redirect::to('login');
    });

    //login get
    Route::get('login','AuthController@showLogin');

    //login for form
    Route::post('login','AuthController@postLogin');

    //routes for admin
    Route::group(array('before' => 'adminFilter'),function()
    {
        Route::get('/adminHomePage',function()
        {
            return View::make('adminHome');
        });
    });

    //route for common user
    Route::group(array('before' => 'commonUserFilter'),function()
    {
        Route::get('/commonUserPage',function()
        {
            return View::make('commonPage');
        });
    });

    Route::get('logout','AuthController@logout');
?>
```

file filters.php

```
<?php 
    Route::filter('adminFilter', function($route, $request)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->profile != 1)
        {
            return Redirect::to('/logout');
        }
    });

    Route::filter('commonUserFilter',function($route, $request)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->profile != 2)
        {
            return Redirect::to('/logout');
        }
    });
?>
```

file AuthController.php

```
<?php
    public function showLogin()
    {
        return View::make('login');
    }

    public function postLogin()
    {
        //Get user data from login form 
        $user = array(
        'user' => Input::get('username'),
        'password' => Input::get('password'));

        if(Auth::attempt($user,true))
        {           
            switch (Auth::user()->profile) 
            {
                case 1:
                    //home admin
                    return Redirect::to('/adminHomePage');
                    break;

                case 2:
                    //home common user
                    return Redirect::to('/commonUserPage');
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::to('login')
            ->with('mensaje_error','Incorrect data.')
            ->withInput();
        }
    }

    public function logOut()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        return Redirect::to('/login')
        ->with('mensaje_error', 'Your session was closed.');        
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why don't you test it and see what happens? Looks correct to me

Comment: I would redirect the users to home rather then logging them out when they are not able to view a page. ofcourse, it depends on what you are making.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i run the example and it work ok. I was posted this for to receive comments and suggestions and maybe show a way to make a profile administration.

Answer (score 0):

One security issue (If you are using Laravel 4 +)

In routes.php:

```
Route::post('name', Controller@class);
```

Change it to:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'csrf'), function() {

  Route::post('name', Controller@class);

});
```

In your form, you have to add this: `{{ Form::token() }}`.

---

One little tip: I prefer to give all your routes a unique names.. How this works can you find [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#named-routes).

Comment: Thank you WQuaniran. I'll use this.